# How to add Sub total row and grand total row using linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to add the sub total row for each **BusinessTypeCode** and grand total for all **BusinessTypeCode**. How can I add these two rows in my linq and put the below of each businesstypecode.

**MY CURRENT CODE**

```
var query = (from _transaction in _entities.Transactions
             join _cd in _entities.Organisations on _transaction.Refno equals _cd.Refno
             join _b in _entities.BusinessType on _transaction.BusinessTypeCode equals _b.BusinessTypeCode
             group new
             {
                 _trans = _transaction,
                 cd = _cd,
             }
             by new { _transaction.BusinessTypeCode,_transaction.Refno, _cd.BusinessName, _b.Description } into _group
             orderby _group.Key.BusinessTypeCode
             select new
             {
                 BusinessTypeCode = _group.Key.BusinessTypeCode,
                 BusType = _group.Key.BusinessTypeCode + " - " +_group.Key.Description,
                 BusName = _group.Key.BusinessName,
                 BusL = _group.Sum(x=>x._trans.BusL),
                 BusInterrest = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.BusInterrest),
                 BusAdmin = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.BusAdmin),
                 BusPenalty = _group.Sum(x => x._trans.BusPenalty),
                 TotalBusCollected =_group.Sum(x=>x._trans.TotalBusCollected)
             });
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(query.CopyToDataTable());
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
var subtotal = query.GroupBy(x=>x.BusinessTypeCode ).Select(s=>new
{
    BusinessTypeCode =s.Key,
    BusLSub = s.Sum(x=>x.BusL),
    BusInterrestSub = s.Sum(x=>x.BusInterrest),
    BusAdminSub = s.Sum(x=>x.BusAdmin),
    BusPenaltySub = s.Sum(x=>x.BusPenalty),
    TotalBusCollectedSub = s.Sum(x=>x.TotalBusCollected),
});
foreach (var a in subtotal)
{
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    dt.NewRow();
    dt.Rows.Add(a.BusLSub, a.BusInterrestSub, a.BusAdminSub, a.BusPenaltySub, a.TotalBusCollectedSub );
}
return ds;
```

**Current Output**

```
BusType        |BusName   | BusL  |BusInterest|BusAdmin| BusPenalty|TotalBusCollected
1 - ACCOUNTING |HIGHVELD  |-23.91 | 0         |-22.84  | 0         |-46.75
1 - ACCOUNTING |BHP       |-50.81 |-79.21     |-76     |-20.02     |-226.04
2 - FOOD       |SAB       |-14.18 |-435.97    |-2.57   |-67.55     |-520.27
2 - FOOD       |DISTIL    |-43.05 |0          |-66,59  |0          |-109.64
3 - MINING     |ANGLOGOLD |-4.43  |0          |-72     |0          |-76.43
   -74.72      |-79.21    |-98.84 |-20.02     |-272.79
   -57.23      |-435.97   |-69.16 |-67.55     |-629.91
   -4.43       |0         |-72    |0          |-76.43
```

How can I push it into where `BusinessTypeCode` =BusinessTypeCode  ?

**OUTPUT SUPPOSE TO BE LIKE**

```
   BusType     |BusName   | BusL  |BusInterest|BusAdmin| BusPenalty|TotalBusCollected
1 - ACCOUNTING |HIGHVELD  |-23.91 | 0         |-22.84  | 0         |-46.75
1 - ACCOUNTING |BHP       |-50.81 |-79.21     |-76     |-20.02     |-226.04
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
Sub Total                 |-74.72 |-79.21     |-98.84  |-20.02     |-272.79
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
 2 - FOOD      |SAB       |-14.18 |-435.97    |-2.57   |-67.55     |-520.27
 2 - FOOD      |DISTIL    |-43.05 |0          |-66,59  |0          |-109.64
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
Sub Total                 |-57.23 |-435.97    |-69.16  |-67.55     |-629.91
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
3 - MINING     |ANGLOGOLD |-4.43  |0          |-72     |0          |-76.43
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
Sub Total                 |-4.43  |0          |-72     |0          |-76.43
--------------------------+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------------
GRAND TOTAL               |-136.38|-515.38    |-240    |-87.57     |-979.13
```

Comment: that's too much code. Post the structure of the classes, and explain what you want to return

Comment: post your attempt and get it fixed..don't outsource your job to others :-)

Comment: And what's the current output of your code attempt?

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado I have edited my code please have a look on it. I added the current output.

Comment: @arviman I have edited my code I included the current out put. Please read it and tell me where I have messed up thing or what can I add so that my code can add sub total at the end of group by **BusinessTypeCode**.

Comment: @Dlamini.M Try ordering the original query by the bustype / busname then loop through checking for the bustype to change (calcuating the total as you loop), and when the bustype value changes then you add a new subtotal row to the table. So you could remove your sub group by.

Comment: In addition to what @Dlamini.M mention, you can append a new row to the original DataTable Rows using Rows.InsertAt. So everytime the BusType changes, insert the corresponding subtotal in between the rows when the change was detected.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado can you please give me a little code for example may be please.

Comment: @Dlamini.M - it's always better when you comment on answers\provide feedback if you were able to incorporate suggestions instead of just asking for something and never returning to the site.

Comment: @arviman sorry man I forgot. Your code on `var lastRecord = ds.Tables[0].Rows.LastOrDefault(r=>r["BusType"]==item.BusTypeCode);` LastOrDefault is not supported in that line. But I am trying to solve my problem in other way.

Comment: @Dlamini.M that's not my code. It is John's . Anyway..you can always comment on the relevant answers themselves.

Comment: @arviman sorry man I made a mistake. I will comment brother.  But thanks for reminding me Sir.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need is some sort of interleaving. I haven't tested this but the idea you want is similar to the following (assuming you have a class called BusRow instead of your anonymous type). I've also taken the liberty of making the subrow's type the same as BusRow, but this need not be the case when you do it.

```
public static IEnumerable<BusRow> Interleave(List<BusRow> rowItems, List<BusRow> subTotalItems)
{
   for(int i = 0 ; i < rowItems.Count; ++i)
   {
     yield return rowItems[i];
     if(i > 0 && rowItems[i].BusinessTypeCode != rowItems[i-1].BusinessTypeCode)
     {
       yield return subTotalItems.Single(x => x.BusinessTypeCode == rowItems[i-1].BusinessTypeCode);
     }
   }
   yield return subTotalItems.Single(x => x.BusinessTypeCode == rowItems[rowItems.Count-1].BusinessTypeCode);
}
```

Of course you're going to change your original query to return BusRow like:

```
var subtotal = query.GroupBy(x=>x.BusinessTypeCode ).Select(s=>new BusRow
{
    BusinessTypeCode =s.Key,
    BusL = s.Sum(x=>x.BusL),
    BusInterrest = s.Sum(x=>x.BusInterrest),
    BusAdmin = s.Sum(x=>x.BusAdmin),
    BusPenalty = s.Sum(x=>x.BusPenalty),
    TotalBusCollected = s.Sum(x=>x.TotalBusCollected),
});
```

Then call

```
var interleaved = Interleave(query, subtotal);
foreach (var a in interleaved)
{
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    dt.NewRow();
    if(String.isNullOrEmpty(a.BusName)//format your subtotal row as you like - add --rows before and after
       dt.Rows.Add(a.BusL, a.BusInterrest, a.BusAdmin, a.BusPenalty, a.TotalBusCollected ); 
   else
     dt.Rows.Add(a.BusinessTypeCode, a.BusName, a.BusL, a.BusInterrest, a.BusAdmin, a.BusPenalty, a.TotalBusCollected ); //normal row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am currently on mobile I won't be able to verify this piece of code.

You can do something like this:

```
foreach(var item in subtotal)
{
   var lastRecord = ds.Tables[0].Rows.LastOrDefault(r=>r["BusType"]==item.BusTypeCode);
   var lastIndex = ds.Tables[0].Rows.IndexOf(lastRecord);
   DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
   dr["BusType"] = item.BusTypeCode;
   // etc.
   ds.Tables[0].Rows.InserAt(dr, lastIndex);
}

// insert the grand total row at the end

return ds;
```

This is just to show the idea on how you can transform the current DataSet output to your desired output.